# Ltac unification variable containing locally-bound variables

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

The Ltac chapter of [CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/), shows a "faulty" tactic:

```
Theorem t1' : forall x : nat, x = x.
  match goal with
    | [ |- forall x, ?P ] => trivial
  end.
```

The book then explains

```
The problem is that unification variables may not contain locally bound variables.
In this case, [?P] would need to be bound to [x = x], which contains the local quantified
variable [x].  By using a wildcard in the earlier version, we avoided this restriction.
```

However, the tactic above actually works in Coq 8.11!

Can unification variables now contain locally-bound variables? If so, is there any difference between the above and

```
Theorem t1' : forall x : nat, x = x.
  match goal with
    | [ |- forall x, _ ] => trivial
  end.
```

(where we replaced `?P` by `_`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `?P` and `_` is that you can actually refer to `P` in the branch. Unfortunately, `P` is an open term, so it might quickly end up being ill-formed, so there is not much you can do with it. So, I would not rely on it. It is better to use `forall x, @?P x` as a pattern, so that `P` is a closed term.

Answer (score 1):

The book provides some more info later on:

```
Actually, the behavior demonstrated here applies to Coq version 8.4,
but not 8.4pl1.  The latter version will allow regular Ltac pattern
variables to match terms that contain locally bound variables, but a
tactic failure occurs if that variable is later used as a Gallina term.
```

This means that in

```
Ltac dummy :=
  match goal with
  | [ H: forall x, ?P |- _ ] => assert True
  end.

Lemma foo (a x : nat) :
  (forall n, n = 42) ->  
  True.
Proof.
  intros.
  dummy.
```

the `dummy` tactic can be applied (because we match `?P` but don't refer to it later on), but if we change `dummy` to be

```
Ltac dummy :=
  match goal with
  | [ H: forall x, ?P |- _ ] => assert ?P
  end.
```

then that'll fail because we're referring to `?P`, which is potentially an open term.